# Call a method with childViewControllers on the same viewController

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to know how to call a method in childViewController01 from childViewController02.
These ViewControllers are declared on the parentViewController, as follows.

○ParentViewController.m:

```
ChildViewController01 *childViewController01 = [[ChildViewController01 alloc] init];
[self.view addSubView:childViewController01];

ChildViewController02 *childViewController02 = [[ChildViewController02 alloc] init];
[self.view addSubView:childViewController02];
```

I know the way to call parentViewController's method from childViewController01.

○ParentViewController.m:

```
childrenViewController01.childDelegate01 = self;
```

○ChildrenViewController01.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id childDelegate01;
```

○ChildrenViewController01.m:

```
[childDelegate01 performSelector:@selector(parentMethod:) withObject:hogeObj];
```

so, I can call childViewControllers's method from parentViewController

○ParentViewController.m:

```
- (void) parentMethod:(id)hogeObj {
    [childViewController02 childMethod02];
}
```

This is so tiring. I'd like to call childMethod02 from childViewController01 directly.
If you know how, please let me know a good way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the reason you use view controllers at all is to keep things separate and tidy. One view controller shouldn't really know anything about its siblings; it's only responsibility is managing it's view and child view controllers. The parent view controller should be in charge of managing the sibling view controllers. Your options to do this are to tell the parent view controller what you want to happen and have the parent send the message to the other view controller, "pollute" the state of the view controllers with references to each other like Metabble suggested, or use a notification pattern.

I've often used NSNotificationCenter for this purpose. Register for the notifications in each view controller and then post notifications to trigger the method calls in the other view controllers.

Comment: Thank you, jxpx777.I try to use a notification pattern.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the controller's, give them references to each other and store them.